# How to loosen access restrictions for a single page in Confluence?

Tags: permissions, confluence

I have a Confluence space which is viewed only by my users. Now I have this single page that I want to have write-enabled for anybody. How can I make a single page accessible?

I do not want to set the space to read/write and manually lock all other pages as this is an error prone process which we might forget sometimes when creating new pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an exact solution for what you want. The permissions are structured in a top-to-down hierarchy. The only way that I can think of is to create a separate space for such pages with special permissions and link your original pages to pages in that space.

Comment: +1 for this. Setting a space to write access and restricting access per page is the only possible way. Placing these pages in a special space will make it much easier.

Comment: While I am personally not satisfied with the provided solution (a 2nd space does not blend in into the tree directory structure, keyword matching gets more difficult, ...) I think this is a shortcoming of confluence and can currently not be solved at all.